# Dealing with private default constructor

Tags: c++, class, assignment-operator, default-constructor

I'm working with a library which has a `class X`, whose default constructor is declared private.

Note that `class X` supports assignment operator.

I want to implement a class which includes class X.

```
class MyClass
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    Z z;
public:
    MyClass(X xv, Y yv, Z zv);
};
```

My purpose for implementing this class is that I've to insert this triplet value into a list.

But I'm not able to implement this class as the default constructor of `X` is declared private, also I won't prefer meddling with code of `X` as rest of the library functions depend on it.

Can I use the fact that `class X` has an assignment operator, to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Edit 1: There is no other constructor available for that class.

Comment: Why is the default constructor of X private? Is there another constructor available? It's probably for a reason that this constructor has been made private.

Comment: *Why* do you need to default-construct the objects? Perhaps it's a flaw in your design? Or in the implementation of your design? And I don't see anything in the little code you show that demands any default construction.

Comment: If you can show the code that's attempting to use a default constructor, maybe we can suggest an alternative that doesn't.

Comment: I think that you’ve missed the *initializer list* concept. Read about them in your favorite C++ book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a default constructor, and it's declared private. g++ returns following error "field of type 'StateID' has private default constructor" [stateID is the X I've mentioned here]

Comment: *My purpose for implementing this class is that I've to insert this triplet value into a list.* --> Why not just use `std::tuple<X,Y,Z>`?

Comment: @rustyx I'll think about it. But a class will be highly appreciated since I might have to include some functions for the ease of usage.

Comment: I assume there is a friend declaration for some class or function, which can instantiate...? Or a factory function in the class...? Supposedly someone designed X this way for a reason.

Comment: If there's no other constructor for that class, except the `private` default constructor, then perhaps it's supposed to be a *singleton* class? If you didn't create the class `X` you need to talk to the person or persons who did, and ask them about the design and why they chose what they did.

Comment: @ravnsgaard Yes there is friend declration for two classes in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly a copy constructor.  (It would be a very strange class that had an assignment operator but not a copy constructor.)  If the class author has not declared a copy constructor, the compiler will create one for them.

Your problem is that you are writing:

```
MyClass::MyClass(X xv, Y yv, Z zv)
    // x, y, z default constructed here.
{
    x = xv; y = yv; z = zv;
}
```

What you need, is to copy construct x,y,z directly (look up "initializer list".  So:

```
MyClass::MyClass(X xv, Y yv, Z zv)
: x(xv), y(yv), z(zv)
{
}
```

Having said that, you are passing xv etc by value.  It would be much more natural to write it as:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const X& xv, const Y& yv, const Z& zv)
: x(xv), y(yv), z(zv)
{
}
```

(and change the declaration as well of course)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems I have misunderstood the concept of initializer list all along. Can you explain why is it more natural to write the second version?

Comment: If X, Y, and Z are expensive to construct, the latter version avoids constructing an expensive temporary on the stack.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks :-)

Comment: @LaschetJain As well as the performance, it seems strange to construct a copy on the stack, and then use that to construct a copy in the member object.  Just pass a reference on the stack, and create the copy directly in the member variable.  (If the constructor is inlined, it makes it slightly easier for the optimizer to just copy the original object too - it doesn't have to worry about eliding side effects in the destructor).